# Run External Javascript File Again Upon React Conditional Change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

***Please read the entire question before answering.***

So I have a vanilla javascript file that I am using to try to activate a fetch request whenever a button is pressed in a separate react file. This vanilla javascript file is NOT within the src folder that the react file is. It is in the public folder, where the index.html is. For the purposes of this, it needs to stay there.

Background.js:

```
function clickTest() {
  fetch('https://connect.smartpathed.com/chrometest');
}

try {
  document.getElementById("test-button").addEventListener('click', clickTest);
}
catch(e) {
  function errorCatch() {
    return;
  }
}
```

**The React component will not be listed here because it is over 2000 lines of code and 95% of it is not pertinent to this question. Just know that there are two conditional statements in the render, and a button with an id in the return statement that I am trying to access.**

The react Component that I am using is split up into two conditional statements upon the render.
Upon the first load, the code above works fine targeting a specific id, but the moment that it switches to the other conditional statement (the one that does not render on load), and I have a similar button with the same id (note that these are separate tests and the button only exists once in both cases, so there is no id clashing), there is no input from the document.getElementById() and the code breaks.
**If I wanted to keep this flow within my react file, I know I would just use refs, but this vanilla JavaScript file above needs to stay as a separate file.**

My index.html in the root directory is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Think. Future. Workforce. Connect.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src = "background.js"></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The div with the id of root represents the react code, and then the JavaScript file is the background.js added at the bottom of the body. **So how would I go about getting the id of an element that's in a conditional statement that's not the one that's activated upon page load?** I have tried putting the background.js inside of the component at the end, but it still doesn't work. Is there any way to activate the background.js again when the condition is changed within the JavaScript component?

Comment: Is that the entirety of `background.js`? Seems you are looking for a way to reestablish the correct "connected" onClick callback handler? What if you made `clickTest` globally accessible?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really such a thing as "run a file" once you're in the browser. The `<script>` tag essentially says, "download the javascript from this url and immediately evaluate it". Since your code is executing in the root of the script, it's a one-and-done operation. **All of this happens before React even initializes your application.**

If you want to be able to wait and call it later, make a function that attaches the event handler.

```
function clickTest() {
  fetch('https://connect.smartpathed.com/chrometest');
}

// would probably make more sense to pass the element or at
// least the selector in here
function addTestHandler() {
  try {
    document.getElementById("test-button").addEventListener('click', clickTest);
  }
  catch(e) {
    function errorCatch() {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Then your react component could call it after render such as:

```
useEffect(() => addTestHandler(), [])
```

I have to say, though, that having javascript in the `public` folder of a react app is suspicious, especially since you're hardcoding the id of an element rendered by React.

Comment: I understand the suspicion. I didn't want to include EVERY single detail in here, but essentially this is for a chrome extension that needs to use gapi and should stay in public folder so that way it can be accessed upon build. Since the framework for the API I'm using is already built out on the web app side of this using React, I need a way to navigate it. Thank you for your answer!